# python is there a way to delete from termimanl/console already printed result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple SSH python module.
In this module I need to detect special characters like tab('\t'), enter('\n') and backspace('\b').
I managed to handle the autocomplete of tab on new line with enter.
However, I cannot simply delete a character.
if i try:

```
print('\b',end='',flush=True)
```

It will not delete the last character printed character but will ignore the next coming one.
In C it's way simpler...

how can I delete already printed characters in a python console(in similar way its possible to delete characters in the built in module 'input')?